# How to show data with for using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

my coding PHP

```
$makan = array('Nasi Goreng','Nasi Kuning','Nasi Liwet','Soto Sokaraja');

for ($x=0;$x<$lama; $x++) {
    $hari = $x+1;
    echo"Day $hari : ";                 
    for ($c=0;$c<3;$c++){
        $satu_makan=$makan_tmp[$c+$y];
        echo $makan[$satu_makan].", ";                                                                  
    };
    echo"<br />";
    $y = $c+0;
}
```

I have data from table pesan_makan

```
id_paket   |  paket_makan  
1          |  3,1,0, 3,2,1, 2,1,0
```

Paket_makan from tabel paket_makan

```
id_makan  | nama_makan
1           Nasi Goreng 
2           Nasi Kuning
3           Nasi Liwet
5           Soto Sokaraja
```

my problem view data :

```
Day 1 : Soto Sokarja, Nasi Kuning, Nasi Goreng,
Day 2 : Soto Sokarja, Nasi Liwet, Nasi Kuning,
Day 3 : Soto Sokarja, Nasi Liwet, Nasi Kuning,
```

I want view data :

```
Day 1 : Soto Sokarja, Nasi Kuning, Nasi Goreng,
Day 2 : Soto Sokarja, Nasi Liwet, Nasi Kuning,
Day 3 : Nasi Liwet, Nasi Kuning, Nasi Goreng,
```

Comment: Where do you define `$y` and what is initialized to (what is its first value)? Same questions for `$makan_tmp`

Answer (score 1):

First of all it will be great if you could elaborate on how do you initiate `$lama` and `$y` vars.

Secondly, you use `$y = $c+0;` where `$c` isn't well define, it's like use `$y=3`.

Third please consider of using

```
for ($x=1;$x<$lama; $x++) {
```

instead of

```
for ($x=0;$x<$lama; $x++) {    
$hari = $x+1;`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lama = $uk['lama_pesan'];
$makan = array('Nasi Goreng','Nasi Kuning','Nasi Liwet','Soto Sokaraja');

for ($x=0;$x<$lama; $x++) {
    $hari = $x+1;
    echo"Day $hari : ";                 
    for ($c=0;$c<3;$c++){
        $satu_makan=$makan_tmp[$c+$y];
        echo $makan[$satu_makan].", ";                                                                  
    };
    echo"<br />";
    $y = $c+$hari-1;
}
```

Now my problem data in Day 3:

```
Day 1 : Soto Sokarja, Nasi Kuning, Nasi Goreng,
Day 2 : Soto Sokarja, Nasi Liwet, Nasi Kuning,
Day 3 : Nasi Liwet, Nasi Kuning, Nasi Liwet,
```

Output Day 3 should be `Nasi Liwet, Nasi Kuning, Nasi Goreng,`

for ($c=0;`$c<3`;$c++){

```
$c<3 -> declaration eat 3 times a day (devide array into 3 part from  pesan_makan field paket_makan)
```

Comment: is this an extension to your question? if so you should edit it rather than post as an answer.